# beyondcomare4 Problem with class file comparison

Tags: beyondcompare4

I use the beyondcompare software to compare the class code, but when the software opens the class file, it prompts a conversion error!

More strange is that my local compiled class can be converted, compiled on the server, the downloaded class can not be converted

I tried to compare 2 identical classes, one is server, one is local, and jd-gui is converted to java file comparison without any difference.

I downloaded it on the official website (https://www.scootersoftware.com/download.php?zz=kb_moreformatsv4), which is your conversion tool, Java class to source

The problem is as shown below, the class on the right shows a conversion error.
[image]
<sub>(source: [sinaimg.cn](http://ww1.sinaimg.cn/large/9b13c8fdly1g2txb6cyswj21hc0qhad7.jpg))</sub>

The following figure is to decompile the two classes into java code, without any inconsistency.
[image]
<sub>(source: [sinaimg.cn](http://ww1.sinaimg.cn/large/9b13c8fdly1g2txcm4spyj21hc0rbn1k.jpg))</sub>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like the file format has a problem with Unicode/Chinese characters in the file name/path.

To fix the problem in Beyond Compare 4:

1. Open **Tools > File Formats**.
2. Select the **Java Class to Source** file format.
3. Go to the **Conversion** tab.
4. Change the dropdown **External program (Unicode filenames)** to **External program (ANSI filenames)**, then **Save**.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, I followed the steps, but still did not solve the problem!

Comment: Solved, I tried to change the Chinese path to English, and the problem was solved. thank you very much!